# I would like to know how to install and use mathlive in NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

please help me I'd like to know why it doesn't work or if I'm doing it wrong.

I npm i mathlive to get input. And following the implementation of the nuxt plugins in the documentation doesn't work.

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Nuxtnumer',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: ['./plugins/mathlive-vue.js'],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
    baseURL: '/',
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ['mathlive-vue']
  },
}
```

file mathlive-vue.js in directory plugins

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import * as Mathlive from 'mathlive';
import Mathfield from 'mathlive/dist/vue-mathlive.mjs'

Vue.use(Mathlive,Mathfield)
```

Error:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                             friendly-errors 19:26:11

ERROR  in ./node_modules/mathlive/dist/vue-mathlive.mjs                                                            friendly-errors 19:26:11

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:342)                                                                       friendly-errors 19:26:11
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /** MathLive 0.69.11 */

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used mathlive specifically, but I read your question and suspected that:

```
transpile: ['mathlive-vue']
```

Should be:

```
transpile: ['vue-mathlive']
```

becase the output complains about ./node_modules/mathlive/dist/vue-mathlive.mjs specifically.

I spun up a quick app and was able to recreate your error by copying your transpile config. Switching to vue-mathline resolved the error for me.

In case you (or anyone else who finds this question) are wondering what's going on- mathlive code uses ES modules, which cannot be executed in Node (the server side of your Nuxt app). Therefore you need to let Nuxt know that those files should be transpiled (made compatible with node) in order for them to work.

Comment: It's a webpack loader error tho. Sure it's related? Maybe the module is just not able to load the dedicated file extension?

Comment: Hmm you make a good point- I was able to resolve the issue, but that isn't the same as understanding it completely. My understanding was that in Nuxt apps, any ES6 module code would need to be transpiled before it could run server-side, and by adding files to the transpile option in nuxt.config, webpack takes care of things.  If you have time to dig into the problem a little deeper, I'm sure OP and anyone else reading this would appreciate a better answer.

Comment: Usually, this error is about the extension that is passed to Webpack. Let's say if matlab uses a `.mat` file extension, it will need to be explained to Webpack what kind of loader to use for this specific format unlike `.js` that Webpack already knows what to do with.

Comment: Hmm, ok- I was under the impression the default Nuxt (reasonbly recent) webpack config used babel-loader to resolve mjs. If I run ```nuxt webpack --dev```, I can see an entry in the rules for ```.mjs```. However, I still receive the error unless I transpile ```vue-mathlive```. I'm no webpack expert, so there is likely a lot more going on than I realise!

Comment: `.js` or `.mjs` are still JS so well known. If you give it a `.yolo` extension, it will probably not know what to do with it. A loader is to know what/how to load a specific file extension AFAIK.

Comment: Got it, but with that and the context of OPs question in mind- why would webpack complain about an ```.mjs``` file in this case? It seems to point to ```vue-mathlive.mjs``` as the problem file, suggesting a loader is required to handle it, however as you mention (and I agree) this shouldn't be a problem unless you intend to run the code on the node side?

Comment: Oh you're probably right, the `.mjs` extension is maybe the culprit as the error says. I thought it was linking to this line but was actually about something else (a matlab imported just after that OP have not shown). So yeah, `.mjs` is probably not supported by default with Webpack4. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

I use the settings below in my nuxt.config.js, without this I can't use mathlive correctly.
You can try it out.

```
  build: {
    modules: ['mathlive'],
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
    }
  }
```

I got this idea from [here](https://github.com/leerobert/nuxt-mathlive/blob/master/nuxt.config.js)